# stack frame on a binary tree traversal

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am having a hard time understanding the stack frame picture of a binary tree traversal

I have this function to calculate the height of a binary tree starting with the root node

```
public static int height(TreeNode<String> t){
        if(t == null)
            return -1;
        int left = height(t.left);
        System.out.println("left " +left);
        int right = height(t.right);
        System.out.println("right " +right);

        if(left > right)
            return left + 1;
        else
            return right + 1;

    }
```

I have a binary tree setup as follows

```
             Root
            /    \
           A      B
```

The returned height value is 1 which is correct but I am having a hard time understanding the stack frame flow of the two recursive functions. What is the flow order like?

I get the following out values on my two print statements

```
left -1
right -1
left 0
left -1
right -1
right 0
```

Comment: BTW is Root also a node, or is it just a pointer to the tree? It it's a node, then shouldn't the tree height be 2 in  this case? IOW what is the height of a tree with one node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executions of `height` follow the tree shape in order.

`height` is called first on `Root` and then recursively on `Root.left` in line 4 and then again recursively on `Root.left.left`, which is `null`.  At this point the last execution of `height` returns `-1` and terminates.  The remaining last execution assigns this to `left` and prints it.

This same execution nex calls `height` on `Root.left.right`.  This is also `null`, so  `-1` is returned and printed, after which the if statement computes `-1 + 1 == 0` and returns this.

We are now back to the call on `Root.left`, and the returned value `0` is assigned to `left` and is printed, whereupon the same execution calls `height` again and again on down to `Root.right.left`, which is `null`, so again `-1` is printed.

You should see the pattern at this point.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Helped me clear a lot of things. I was confused on how double recursion works but now I guess I am getting the picture somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

```
left -1   A.left is null
right -1  A.right is null
left 0    Root.left is A
left -1   B.left is null
right -1  B.right is null
right 0   Root.right is B
```

But if you want a clearer picture you should probably code something like

```
public static int height(TreeNode<String> t){
  if(t == null)
    return -1;
  int left = height(t.left);
  System.out.println(t+" left "+left);
  int right = height(t.right);
  System.out.println(t+" right "+right);
  if(left > right)
    return left + 1;
   else
    return right + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is your problem, but here it goes:

**1)** Initial call to `height` with root node

**2)** First recursive call to `height` with `A` node

**3)** Second recursive call to `height` with `A.left` (which is `null`)

**4)** First `if` statement fires, returns `-1` - back to after the call in point 3)

**5)** First print statement - "left -1". Third recursive call to `height` with `A.right` (which is `null`)

**6)** `if` fires again, returns `-1` - back to after the call in point 5)

**7)** Second print statement - "right -1".

**8)** `left` is `-1` and `right` is `-1`, hence `right + 1` is returned (`0`)- back to after the call in point 2)

**9)** Third print statement - "left 0".

**10)** Next recursive call of `height` with `B` node. Repeat steps 2-8 substituting `B` for `A`. Repeating this yields two print statements "left -1" and "right -1".

**11)** After getting back, `right` is `0` and thus the last print statement reads "right 0".

**12)** `left` is `0` and `right` is `0`, hence `right + 1` is returned